# Suggestion to retag Microsoft Store

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, retagging

The Microsoft Store:

https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Store

was previously called the "Windows Store". To that end, I see questions under both:

- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-store
- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store

would it be okay if I update the old tags to all say "Microsoft Store"? Or what is the process?

Comment: I think we can synonymise them - which would be a better idea - since it 'links' the two, so I'd hold off on updates first until there's a proper answer and consensus

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the two tags

I'd say *don't* retag, but there's a few blockers to what to do

- Having a good tag wiki for the one we're keeping seems essential, and include the fact that it *was* called the microsoft store.

This can be done now

- is the 'store' name changed for windows 8 systems? I might be able to check on this if I can dig up one of my cheap chinese tablets that run that.

Wikipedia indicates that you won't be able to upgrade apps on the old storefronts after some date, so that's an arguement for keeping it separate. Any 8.x system would *not* have microsoft store ever.

- Is it worth creating a tag synonym ? that would mean we don't need to retag, and would 'merge' the tags in a fairly neat way.

Naturally only with a complete  1-1 mapping between them. Does not quite feel like that's the case.

As such, it might a good idea to do retags on a *case by case* basis as you encounter them only where the question is *obviously* about the version of the microsoft store named as such on supported windows 10 systems.